# update query with multiple where clauses

Tags: sql

I have a sql update query which looks something like this but does not work.

Could someone help me rectify this:
`abc` is a table with `a_id` and `avlaue` are columns.

So in the query below, I want to make `avalue = null` for `a_id = 1` when `a_id = 2` and its value is either 1, 2 or 3.

```
update abc set avalue = null where a_id = 1 and (a_id = 2 and avlaue IN (1,2,3));
```

Comment: a_id=1 and (a_id=2 and avlaue IN(1,2,3)); should be a_id=1 or (a_id=2 and avlaue IN(1,2,3));

Comment: I want to update when (a_id=2 and avlaue IN(1,2,3)), so or won't work

Comment: yeah it will, the parenthesis will make the predicate id =1 or (id -2 and avalue in (1,2,3))  try it with a select first

Answer (score 3):

The issue with the `and`, use `or` instead of that:

Its not possible that `a_id` can be 1 and 2, try the below:

```
update abc set avalue = null where a_id = 1 or (a_id = 2 and avlaue IN (1,2,3));
```

Comment: a_id with a value 1 will become null only if another row where a_id is 2 and its value is either 1,2 or 3

Answer (score 1):

Try to this

```
 update abc set avalue = null where a_id=1 or (a_id=2 and avlaue IN(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to check like

```
update abc set avalue = null 
where a_id in (1,2) and avlaue IN(1,2,3);
```

Comment: The above query will make a_id 2 also null..I only wnat to chnage a_id 1's value to null.

Comment: Can you post a sample data which will clear the logic much better. am bit confused here as how the updation logic should be? why can't you simply say `where a_id = 1 and avlaue IN(1,2,3);`

Comment: The logic that needs to be satisfied is this: if mpc= 1 OR mpc= 2 OR mpc= 3 then mph's value will be null . So in this case mpc whose id is a_id=2 and value can be 1, 2 or 3, then mph(with a_id =1) will be null